# How do I check latest version of Homebrew?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, homebrew

On OS X I can check which version of homebrew I have installed with `brew -v`. Is there a way to check what the latest version available for installation is?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the git release notes with

```
$ curl -s "https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases" | 
    awk '/true" class="Link--primary/{gsub(/<\/a.*|.*">/, "", $NF); print $NF}' | 
  head -1
3.6.12
```

or, if you want a longer history with date-times.

```
$ curl -s "https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases" | 
    awk '/relative-time.*prefix="" datetime/{sub(/T/, " ", $NF)
      gsub(/.*e="|">/, "", $NF); date = $NF}
         /true" class="Link--primary/{gsub(/<\/a.*|.*">/, "", $NF)
      print $NF"\t"date}'
3.6.12  2022-11-21 14:24:13Z
3.6.11  2022-11-14 14:35:38Z
3.6.10  2022-11-09 17:03:46Z
3.6.9   2022-11-07 14:22:45Z
3.6.8   2022-11-01 12:20:01Z
3.6.7   2022-10-24 12:27:21Z
3.6.6   2022-10-17 13:29:39Z
3.6.5   2022-10-10 11:37:32Z
3.6.4   2022-10-03 09:09:57Z
3.6.3   2022-09-26 13:06:10Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always run `brew update` to update your `brew` and formulae.

```
$ brew update --help
Usage: brew update [options]

Fetch the newest version of Homebrew and all formulae from GitHub using git(1)
and perform any necessary migrations.

      --merge                      Use git merge to apply updates (rather than
                                   git rebase).
      --auto-update                Run on auto-updates (e.g. before brew
                                   install). Skips some slower steps.
  -f, --force                      Always do a slower, full update check (even
                                   if unnecessary).
  -q, --quiet                      Make some output more quiet
  -v, --verbose                    Print the directories checked and git
                                   operations performed.
  -d, --debug                      Display a trace of all shell commands as they
                                   are executed.
  -h, --help                       Show this message.
```